# C application high CPU consumption in a raspberry using exagear

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to run a C x86 application in a raspberry using Exagear.

In my laptop the CPU consumption of the C applications while is running is about 50-60%. When I run the same C application in the raspberry, the CPU consumption is about 300%. I don't know why this CPU consumption difference between my laptop and the raspberry using exagear.

My raspberry is a Quad core Cortex A53 processor @ 1.2 GHz with Videocore IV GPU 1GB LPDDR2 RAM. While my laptop virtual machine have two processors and 4GB RAM.

I'm thinking that maybe there's some kind of problema using my C application with exagear.

I would like to know if I could check more things to try to figure out which is the cause of this high CPU consumption.

Comment: And exagear is an *emulator* ?

Comment: Lots of possible reasons... A) Raspberry Pi probably isn't nearly as powerful as the processor that's in your computer... B) emulators are not efficient C) what OSes are you using? - windows reports `0-100%`, while linux reports `0-(n*100)%` utilization - `400%` for your case / quad core

Comment: @joop https://eltechs.com/product/exagear-desktop/

Comment: @Attie I'm using a Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)

Comment: @JosephB And on the laptop?

Comment: @Attie Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS xenial

Comment: Depends on what your application is doing (waiting for I/O will reduce CPU usage) and what other processes are running (if none, it can use all of the CPU(s)).

Comment: it is the emulator of the complex CISC processor on the RISC one. I would even expect more overhead to be honest